# How to write IOS unit test case with Python?

Tags: python, ios, unit-testing

Recently in the study of iOS unit testing framework XCTest, would like to package XCTest through Python to reduce the difficulty of writing unit test cases, to achieve the purpose of writing IOS unit test case with Python, but the relevant information is too small, so ask you big god there is What ideas or framework recommended, thank you very much!

Comment: why do you need framework ....follow this documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest and if you find any code related difficulty then ask your question by showing the code here

Comment: XCTest related knowledge I also understand, but the boss want someone who do not understand OC to write OC unit test cases with python, so is there any way feasibility?

Comment: that makes no sense whatsoever to write unit tests in a different language. Writing end-to-end test *might* make sense in other languages or tests similar to selenium make sense, but unit tests in a different language make zero sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!But why unit tests in a different langugae make zero sense? In my opinion, it can reduce the difficulty of writing unit test case at least,so please tell me your proof！